# Is it possible to invite exactly one friend by Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api

Without showing the multiuser invite popup. For example I know the uid and that he/she is not using the app. So I want to offer a button, to invite this person.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `to` parameter of the [request dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) to specify that it should go to a single user.  You can set `frictionlessRequests : true` in `FB.init` so that the first time it will prompt users to allow you to send requests without prompting the user each time.